# $f(z)$ analytic on $D$ with sequence $z_n \in D$ s.t. $|f(z_n)| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Radius of convergence of power series for $f$ is 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analytic-functions

This is a problem from a previous complex analysis qualifying exam that I'm working through to study for my own upcoming exam. I'm feeling pretty clueless on this one.

**Problem:**

Suppose $f(z)$ is an analytic function on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ and that there exists a sequence of points $z_n \in \mathbb{D}$ such that $|f(z_n)| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Prove that the radius of convergence of the power series for $f$ about the origin is equal to 1.

**My thoughts so far:**

If $f(z)$ is analytic on the open unit disk, then there exists a power series centered at the origin. If it's analytic, this power series has only exponents $\geq 0$ and should be convergent everywhere it's analytic. With no singularities, I don't understand how we'd have $|f(z_n)| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. I'm guessing this is a failure to understand how sequences work in the complex plane.

I could use a clear and thorough explanation of what's going on here and direct references to a theorem or topic I can look up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\rho$ be radius of convergence. We have to have $\rho\geqslant1$, since the radius of convergence is always at least as large as the radius of the largest open disk centered at the origin and contained in $\Bbb D$.

Now, suppose that $\rho>1$ and, for each $z\in D_\rho(0)$, let$$F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}z^n.$$Then $|z|<1\implies F(z)=f(z)$. On the other hand, the sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\Bbb Z_+}$ is bounded, and therefore it has a convergent subsequence $\left(z_{n_k}\right)_{k\in\Bbb Z_+}$; let $\omega$ be its limit. Then$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\left|f\left(z_{n_k}\right)\right|=|F(\omega)|,$$which is impossible, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}|f(z_n)|=\infty$.

Comment: Can you clarify why $\rho$ is always at least as large as the radius of the largest open disk centered at the origin and contained in the open unit disk? Is this meaning that it's at least as large as the largest open disk that we know $f$ is analytic on?

Comment: Yes, that's the meaning. And it's a standard Complex Analysis theorem, called *Cauchy-Taylor representation theorem*. You'll find it, for instance, in Reinhold Remmert's *Theory of Complex Functions*, chapter 7, §3.

Comment: I hate to admit it, but I'm actually still confused on this one.  Why is the argument you gave unique to $\rho>1$? Why is this not also an issue for $\rho\leq 1$, since the $z_n$ given that goes to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ is inside the unit disk?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know what is it that you are asking me. Besides, it is *not* true that the $z_n$'s go to $\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, since each $z_n$ belongs to $\Bbb D$.

Comment: I'm sorry... I misstated that. The $|f(z_n)|\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$, per the problem statement. I'm trying to understand what the second part of your argument has to do with $\rho>1$...